# How can I get outer div target with event.target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making web service with javascript (and jQuery), and I'm trying to make custom menu.
But the main point is "Widget's ID which is clicked by user".
I want to return widget's id (like `widget1` or `widget2`),
even if user pressed inner objects (`img`, `textarea`, etc.)
I tried `event.target.id` but it returns inner object's id, not outer div.
How could I solve this problem?

JavaScript and HTML :

```js
$("#wrapper_widgets").bind("contextmenu", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(event.target.id);
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper_widgets">
  <div id="widget1">
    <img src="blablabla.png">
    <textarea id="widget1_textarea">blablabla</textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="widget2" style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 500px; height: 100px;">
    <p id="widget2_timedoc">asdasdasd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `event.stopPropagation()`, before `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is event.target will refer to the element from which the event was originated from, so you will have to find the closest ancestor `widget` element

One easy solution is to use a class to all the widgets and target it

```
<div id="wrapper_widgets">
    <div id="widget1" class="widget">
        <img src="blablabla.png">
        <textarea id="widget1_textarea">blablabla</textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="widget2" class="widget" style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 500px; height: 100px;">
        <p id="widget2_timedoc">asdasdasd</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$("#wrapper_widgets").on("contextmenu", '.widget', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(this.id);
});
```

or

```
$("#wrapper_widgets").bind("contextmenu", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(event.target).closest('.widget').attr('id'));
 });
```

Comment: first solution (bind with class name) didn't worked for me, but second one worked as well. Thanks!

Comment: @MineSky try `$("#wrapper_widgets").on("contextmenu", '.widget', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(this.id);
});` - if the elements are created dynamically

Comment: It also works well. I didn't know that there is better method `.on()` after 1.7

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`.closest('div')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** with `.prop()` to get the immediate ancestor ID.

```
$(event.target).closest('div').prop('id')
```

Note : This would work only if there is no further nesting of `<div>s` inside wrappers.

```
$("#wrapper_widgets").bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(event.target).closest('div').prop('id'));
});
```

```js
$("#wrapper_widgets").bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(event.target).closest('div').prop('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper_widgets">
    <div id="widget1">
        <img src="blablabla.png">
        <textarea id="widget1_textarea">blablabla</textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="widget2" style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 500px; height: 100px;">
        <p id="widget2_timedoc">asdasdasd</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if he has two div then

Comment: Which two div are you referring to?

Comment: i am just asking if  see this  example : <DIV><div><div><textarea></textarea><DIV> if i click on textarea so closest will giv me DIV id or div id

Comment: Yes i see your note , but  i tried this example it will return this capital DIV id but small div is closer then Capital so i confused ? can you please explain me way ?

Comment: Actually, my project have chance to have another div inside of the outer div, it depends on user.

Comment: @KevalBhatt, your nesting is wrong. `<DIV><div><textarea></textarea></div><DIV>` - use this and it will return small `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

In the event function use

```
$(this).parent().prop('id')
```

to get the immediate parent's id of the clicked element. This will always return the immediate parent and not necessarily only divs but in your case it will work and return 'widget1' or 'widget2'.